# On Sencha Touch 2.2.0 it is not possible to enable the default browser scroll

Tags: sencha-touch-2

The new Sencha Touch 2.2.0 has a new configuration parameter on scrollable to don't use the Ext.scroll.Scroller, but actually this is not working.

I am using this to activate the overflow scroll on my container:

```
{
    scrollable: null,
    style: 'overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;'
}
```

How can I use the native scroll ?

Why I need it?
Because I need to use a galaxy-tab-1 the new Ext.scroll.Scroller is faster than 2.1.1 version but the render on this tablet is slow and the new Ext.scroll.Scroller is trying to render 40 fps and the tablet is displaying this slowly.

Actually the setFps() is not working in this version, example:

```
Econtainer.getScrollable().getScroller().setFps(10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Ext.util.Translatable has an slowly PreferredTranslationMethod by default.

You can use:

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'both',
    translatable: {
        translationMethod: 'scrollposition'
    }
},
```

or

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'both',
    translatable: {
        translationMethod: 'csstransform'
    }
},
```

or

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'both',
    translatable: {
        translationMethod: 'cssposition'
    }
},
```